# Excel VBA Conditional Formatting Custom Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets: Sheet2 and Sheet3. The goal was to highlight the cells in column A of sheet3 that has a match in column A of sheet2. Here's sheet2: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKZw3.png). Here's for sheet3: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22B9i.png)

Now I used this formula to determine if there's a match: `=SUM(--(A2=Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4))>0`

Now here's the vba code that I used to implement the conditional formatting:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:A6")
With rng
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=SUM(--(A2=Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4))>0"
    With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
End With
```

So here's the problem: The code only highlights the first cell as shown in the image of sheet3, but there are other cells that met the criteria. I've tried recording the conditional format and run the code but it also does the same. The formula works fine if you do manual conditional formatting. I hope someone can elucidate this problem for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Conditional Formatting (`xlExpression`)

- I would rather use the following formula:

  ```
  =ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4,0))
  ```

  (Replace the commas with semicolons if necessary.)
- I don't know why your formula is not working. As you said, it is applied only to the first cell.

**Links**

- [`FormatConditions object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatconditions)
- [`FormatCondition object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatcondition)
- [`FormatCondition.SetFirstPriority method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatcondition.setfirstpriority)
- [`FormatCondition.StopIfTrue property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatcondition.stopiftrue)

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

' "=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4,0))"
' "=SUM(--(A2=Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4))>0"
Sub cformatExpression()
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:A6")
    With rng.FormatConditions
        .Delete
        .Add xlExpression, , "=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$4,0))"
        ' Refer to last added (our) condition
        ' ('short' for: 'rng.FormatConditions(rng.FormatConditions.Count)').
        With .Parent.FormatConditions(.Count)
            .SetFirstPriority
            With .Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 255
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            '.StopIfTrue = False ' Note, default is 'True' in VBA.
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your formula is much better indeed. Maybe vba with conditional formatting can't process array formulas. I have a question. Is '.Parent.FormatConditions(.Count)' the same with 'rng.FormatConditions(rng.FormatConditions.Count)'?

Comment: In the expression `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")` the parent of `Range("A1")` is `Worksheet("Sheet1")` and the parent of `Worksheet("Sheet1")` is `ThisWorkbook`. To refer to the worksheet you use `.Parent` or `.Worksheet` and to refer to the workbook you use `.Parent.Parent` or `.Worksheet.Parent`

Comment: In this case, it is the same because there is previously `With rng.FormatConditions`. The parent of the expression is `rng` so we could actually use `rng.FormatConditions(.Count)`. The first idea was to not use a variable: `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A2:A6").FormatConditions`. Then `.Parent` would have been the only option. You can try it, just remove the first lines (`Dim...` and `Set...`) and adjust the `With` statement.